# Firefox: Is it possible to create a bookmark for searched history using "chrome://" url

Tags: firefox, search, history

I can create a bookmark in Firefox using the following URL:

```
chrome://browser/content/history/history-panel.xul
```

Is it possible to get a URL with searched keywords, such as `?q=windows` ?

Alternately, is it possible to get a URL of history search results?

(BTW I can do this in Google chrome with, e.g, `chrome://history/?q=Windows`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox can do the trick by using Smart Bookmarks Folders.

If you want to use [Chrome URLs](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Chrome_URLs) itself, there does not seem to be anything relevant. This is because Firefox handles bookmarks and history *not* via Chrome URLs, but via Places.

### What are Smart Bookmarks Folders

This feature is made available since Firefox 3 was released in 2008 back then. Ten years later in 2018, probably remain less known to the end users except for this article on Firefox Help, which does not explain much by itself: [Restore the default Smart Bookmarks Folders](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-default-smart-bookmarks-folders).

The MozillaWiki has the useful information:

> Places is currently enabled for Firefox 3 and greater, powering History and Bookmarks, as well as providing plumbing for Livemarks, Annotations and Microsummaries and the Awesomebar.
>
> -- From [Places on MozillaWiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/index.php?title=Places&oldid=1157175)
>
> Places is designed to be a robust back-end for Bookmarks, History and related components using the mozStorage wrapper for SQLite.
>
> -- From [Places:Design on MozillaWiki](http://wiki.mozilla.org/index.php?title=Places:Design_Overview&oldid=126159)

### Create a Smart Bookmarks Folder

The early documentation of Places could be traced back to [this 2008-dated thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=629560&sid=1429a55f6292b3b52f37985c200d715a) on mozillaZine Forums, whose title "Places query syntax" had quoted "[Places query URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Places_query_URIs)" in the references. In the latter, `places` URI that enables the Smart Bookmarks Folder is explained:

> You can use a `place` URI as a bookmark. For example, if you right-click on the toolbar and choose "New Bookmark," you can enter a `place` URI there to create a new query on your toolbar that, when clicked, will reveal a popup containing the results of the query.

One thing that the documentation did not mention is that "reloading" is required to take effect. Therefore:

- When creating from Bookmarks Toolbar, user will need to hide and unhide toolbar or,
- When creating from Library (shown as "Show All Bookmarks" in menu bar or menu button), user will need to close and reopen the window

This is a better way: Open Library via Chrome URL and reload quickly with one press of key (explained later at below).

Anyway, the created bookmark will auto-magically transform into a Smart Bookmarks Folder. Once transformed, user can *not* edit the same bookmark again. So instead of editing the same bookmark, user will have to create a new bookmark again to use other parameters as user wish.

### Create bookmark for search history

Finally, to the point. To create a bookmark for searched history in Firefox, do the following.

1. Type Chrome URL of Library and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   ```
   chrome://browser/content/places/places.xul
   ```
2. In the sidebar, go to **All Bookmarks** > **Bookmarks Toolbar** (or similar location of choice), then create a New Bookmark.
3. Fill in the **Name** and **Location** with string of choice.

   ```
   Name: History Search 'time'
   Location: place:queryType=0&terms=time
   ```
4. Click **Add** to finish.
5. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to reload Library, then go to the created bookmark.

Following above steps, and perhaps after searching "time" at several sites later, the result is shown in the screenshot at below.

[image: Searched history in Firefox using Smart Bookmarks Folder]

By the way, the searched history using Chrome URL shown by OP does not seem to work in some Chrome-based browsers such as Opera and Vivaldi. The searched history in Firefox is made possible by using Smart Bookmarks Folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gave it a try and it does work as describe. Too bad the bookmark created cannot be edited only the fly.

I would mark it accepted answer but seems like I can't? (There is no option to do this).

Comment: @FractalSpace Below the 'up | votes | down' buttons, there is a grey check mark that is only visible and clickable by OP. Question was asked sometime ago, so you can click instantly. Glad to hear the solution works for you. Also, take [the tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to earn yourself a badge.